# How to link series of swf files to each other?

Tags: animation, flash

I have series of swf files that I want to link them together as bellow:

```
 a.swf -> b.swf > c.swf > .....
```

In fact I am new in flash and I am using Swishmax. 
My files are about 7000, so it is very hard for me to dont link them in batch, so please suggest a way that is simpler to implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chek out SWFLoader from greensock.com
Greensock offers great libraries for AS3 and now also JavaScript. They also have a great Documentation and support as well as community. To you problem though, if with "link" you meant load in composition. Then SWLLoader will do a great job.